# How can I delete objects without complete data by using stata

Tags: stata

I have a large panel dataset that looks as follows.

```
 input id age high weight str6 daily_drink
1 10 110 35 water
1 10 110 35 coffee
1 11 120 38 water
1 11 120 38 coffee
1 12 130 50 water
1 12 130 50 coffee
2 11 118 31 water
2 11 118 31 coffee
2 11 118 31 milk
2 12 123 38 water
2 12 123 38 coffee
2 12 123 38 milk
3 10 98 55 water
3 11 116 36 water
3 12 129 39 water
4 12 125 40 water
 
end
```

However, I would like to use stata to keep objects with complete 10, 11, and 12 age. Looks like this.

```
id  age high    weight  daily_drink
1   10  110     35      water
1   10  110     35      coffee
1   11  120     38      water
1   11  120     38      coffee
1   12  130     50      water
1   12  130     50      coffee
3   10  98      55      water
3   11  116     36      water
3   12  129     39      water
```

However, all the rows are without missing data, so I cannot simply delete the row with missing data. Is there any way to do it? Any suggestion will help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bysort and egen for this. Something along the lines of

```
bysort id: egen has10 = total(age==10)
bysort id: egen has11 = total(age==11)
bysort id: egen has12 = total(age==12)
keep if (has10 != 0) & (has11 != 0) & (has12 != 0)
```

should work (untested). See `help egen` for more info. Install gtools if you have very large data (`ssc install gtools`) and then replace egen by gegen.

Comment: This is I think the plainest road ahead. Note that the last statement can be simplified to `keep if has10  &  has11 & has12` given that non-zero means true and negative results for any variables are impossible.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that works if 10, 11, 12 are the only age values possible:

```
bysort id (age) : gen nvals = sum(age != age[_n-1]) 
by id : replace nvals = nvals[_N] 
keep if nvals == 3
```

Consider also

```
bysort id (age) : gen OK1 = age[1] == 10 & age[_N] == 12 
by id : egen OK2 = max(age == 11) 
keep if OK1 & OK2
```